# Editing records in CGrid view by displaying a dialog box in CButton Column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

In my web application I need to implement  a dialog box for edit button using javascript
and ajax. My code works fine for ajax but i want to display dialog box for  editing records. 
My code

```
$this->widget ( 'zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array (
        'id' => 'store-grid',
        // 'itemsCssClass' => 'table-bordered items',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search (),
        'filter' => $model,
        'columns' => array(
                'id',
                'store_name',
                 'is_deleted',

                 array(
                 'class' =>'CButtonColumn',
                     'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'deleteConfirmation'=>"js:'Do you really want to delete record with Store name '+$(this).parent().parent().children(':nth-child(2)').text()+'?'",

                 'template'=> '{view}{update}{delete}',
                 'buttons'=>array
                 (
                 'view'=>

                 array(
                 'options'=>array(
                 'ajax'   =>array(
                 'type' =>'POST',
                 'url'  => "js:$(this).attr('href')",
                 'update' => '#id_view',
                 ),
                   ),
                   ),

                 'update'=> array
                  (
                  'options' =>array(
                  'ajax'   =>array(
                   'type'   =>'POST' ,
                   'url'    =>"js:$(this).attr('href')",
                   'click'  =>"function(){alert("js:$(this).attr('href')"}",
                    'update'=>'#id_view',

       ),
    ),

                    ),
                    ),
                    ),
        ),                             



                  )
        );









?>
<div id="id_view"></div>
```

I am getting error if i use the click function and then give the url inside the 'alert' function.Is there any way in which I can give the details of the object using "($this)" in the javascript function properly. Any body help me with this I am unable to proceed. I am  getting error for this line of code

```
'click'  =>"function(){alert("js:$(this).attr('href')"}",
```

How should I implement this using javascript? 
This is the html output of the widget

```
    <div class="span-19">
    <div id="content">
        <ul class="breadcrumb"><li><a href="/stores2/"><i class="icon-home"></i></a><span class="divider">/</span></li><li><a href="#">manage</a><span class="divider">/</span></li><li><a href="index">Stores</a><span class="divider">/</span></li></ul>
<div id="dialogUpdatestore">
<div class="divStore"></div>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 'click'  =>"function(){alert("js:$(this).attr('href')"}",
```

to

```
 'click'  =>"js:function(){alert("$(this).attr('href')"}",
```

or this not sure :D

```
 'click'  =>"function(){alert("$(this).attr('href')"}",
```

Comment: what happend? nothing got alerted?

Comment: no. I am getting the output as ajax ,but i want as a dialog box which I am not getting.Should I use some other way  please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be getting your quote marks mixed up. Try changing it to this:

```
'click'  =>"function(){alert($(this).attr('href')}",
```

Comment: No its not working or should I use some other way ? please hellp

Comment: @user2492854 It doesn't really help to just say 'It's not working'. Can you be a bit more specific? Do you get any error messages? What is the html output of the widget? It is what you would expect? Have you tried debugging it? What debugging have you tried? If you can be more specific it will be a big help in trying to help you sort out your problem.

Comment: that is I want the output as a separate pop up dialog box but only its working for ajax. I have pasted the html output of my jui widget

Comment: @user2492854 so your widget isn't outputting anything then? There seems to be no code that relates to a CGridView widget that you have defined there. Is that correct? Iff so, you need to sort that out before you can address the problem of ajax and modal boxes :-)

Comment: My advice would be to start from the least amount of columns you need to generate something on the page, then build your widget up bit by bit, checking each time to make sure it's generating what you would expect. It's easier then to see what you've added that is breaking it.

Comment: can you please tell me how to pass the submit function in javascript from controller.I rectified the errors and I am getting the dialog box but i am unable to update through the dialog box.

Comment: @user2492854 you need to have the submit button on your modal window submit the form to an action of your controller. You then just deal with it in your controller as you would any normal update request. If you're still stuck, I'd suggest starting a new question, as this is different to the question you originally asked.